# iOS8 app extension, tried deleting from project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8-extension

I was looking at the different share extensions for my project but realized it's not quite what I needed, so I deleted the folder and found other installations in build phases I had to delete. But in my info.Plist there was still NSExtension and TRUEPREDICATE that was giving me yellow yield sign when building. I tried to delete the NSExtension Dictionary but it wouldn't build. So I changed TRUEPREDICATE to just a random string to get the message to disappear. But Im worried when I submit to apple it will get declined bc of this. How can I fully remove an app extension from my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete the extension from your targets list in the project settings
2. Delete the extension from your schemes list in Xcode

Comment: happy i helped :) you can select my answer